# datetime.date creating many problems with set_index, groupby, and apply in Pandas 0.8.1

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I'm using Pandas 0.8.1 in an environment where it is not possible to upgrade for bureaucratic reasons.

You may want to skip down to the "simplified problem" section below, before reading all about the initial problem and my goal.

My goal: group a DataFrame by a categorical column "D", and then for each group, sort by a date column "dt", set the index to "dt", perform a rolling OLS regression, and return the DataFrame `beta` of regression coefficients indexed by date.

The end result would hopefully be a bunch of stacked `beta` frames, each one unique to some specific categorical variable, so that the final index would be two levels, one for category ID and one for date.

If I do something like

```
my_dataframe.groupby("D").apply(some_wrapped_OLS_caller)
```

then I am getting frustratingly uninformative `KeyError: 0` errors often, and the tracebacks seems to be choking on datetime issues:

```
/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in set_index(self, keys, drop, inplace, verify_integrity)
   2287             arrays.append(level)
   2288
-> 2289         index = MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=keys)
   2290
   2291         if verify_integrity and not index.is_unique:

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in from_arrays(cls, arrays, sortorder, names)
   1505         if len(arrays) == 1:
   1506             name = None if names is None else names[0]
-> 1507             return Index(arrays[0], name=name)
   1508
   1509         cats = [Categorical.from_array(arr) for arr in arrays]

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in __new__(cls, data, dtype, copy, name)
    102         if dtype is None:
    103             if (lib.is_datetime_array(subarr)
--> 104                 or lib.is_datetime64_array(subarr)
    105                 or lib.is_timestamp_array(subarr)):
    106                 from pandas.tseries.index import DatetimeIndex

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.is_datetime64_array (pandas/src/tseries.c:90291)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    427     def __getitem__(self, key):
    428         try:
--> 429             return self.index.get_value(self, key)
    430         except InvalidIndexError:
    431             pass

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
    639         """
    640         try:
--> 641             return self._engine.get_value(series, key)
    642         except KeyError, e1:
    643             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type == 'integer':

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/src/tseries.c:103842)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/src/tseries.c:103670)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/src/tseries.c:104379)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/src/tseries.c:15547)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/src/tseries.c:15501)()

KeyError: 0
```

If I perform the regression steps manually on each group in the group-by object, one by one, everything works without a hitch.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta as drr

def foo(zz):
    zz1 = zz.sort("dt", ascending=True).set_index("dt")
    r1 = pandas.ols(y=zz1["y1"], x=zz1["x"], window=60, min_periods=12)
    return r1.beta

dfrm_test = pandas.DataFrame({"x":np.random.rand(731), 
                              "y1":np.random.rand(731),
                              "y2":np.random.rand(731), 
                              "z":np.random.rand(731)})

dfrm_test['d'] = np.random.randint(0,2, size= (len(dfrm_test),))
dfrm_test['dt'] = [datetime.date(2000, 1, 1) + drr(days=i) 
                   for i in range(len(dfrm_test))]
```

Now here is what happens when I try to work with these using `groupby` and `apply`:

```
In [102]: dfrm_test.groupby("d").apply(foo)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-345a8d45df50> in <module>()
----> 1 dfrm_test.groupby("d").apply(foo)

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    267         applied : type depending on grouped object and function
    268         """
--> 269         return self._python_apply_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
    270
    271     def aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs):

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _python_apply_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    402             group_axes = _get_axes(group)
    403
--> 404             res = func(group, *args, **kwargs)
    405
    406             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):

<ipython-input-101-8b9184c63365> in foo(zz)
      1 def foo(zz):
----> 2     zz1 = zz.sort("dt", ascending=True).set_index("dt")
      3     r1 = pandas.ols(y=zz1["y1"], x=zz1["x"], window=60, min_periods=12)
      4     return r1.beta

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in set_index(self, keys, drop, inplace, verify_integrity)
   2287             arrays.append(level)
   2288
-> 2289         index = MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=keys)
   2290
   2291         if verify_integrity and not index.is_unique:

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in from_arrays(cls, arrays, sortorder, names)
   1505         if len(arrays) == 1:
   1506             name = None if names is None else names[0]
-> 1507             return Index(arrays[0], name=name)
   1508
   1509         cats = [Categorical.from_array(arr) for arr in arrays]

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in __new__(cls, data, dtype, copy, name)
    102         if dtype is None:
    103             if (lib.is_datetime_array(subarr)
--> 104                 or lib.is_datetime64_array(subarr)
    105                 or lib.is_timestamp_array(subarr)):
    106                 from pandas.tseries.index import DatetimeIndex

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.is_datetime64_array (pandas/src/tseries.c:90291)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    427     def __getitem__(self, key):
    428         try:
--> 429             return self.index.get_value(self, key)
    430         except InvalidIndexError:
    431             pass

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
    639         """
    640         try:
--> 641             return self._engine.get_value(series, key)
    642         except KeyError, e1:
    643             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type == 'integer':

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/src/tseries.c:103842)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/src/tseries.c:103670)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/src/tseries.c:104379)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/src/tseries.c:15547)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/src/tseries.c:15501)()

KeyError: 0
```

If I save the `groupby` object and attempt to apply `foo` myself, then in the straightforward way, this also fails:

```
In [103]: grps = dfrm_test.groupby("d")

In [104]: for grp in grps:
    foo(grp[1])
   .....:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-f215ff55c12b> in <module>()
      1 for grp in grps:
----> 2     foo(grp[1])
      3

<ipython-input-101-8b9184c63365> in foo(zz)
      1 def foo(zz):
----> 2     zz1 = zz.sort("dt", ascending=True).set_index("dt")
      3     r1 = pandas.ols(y=zz1["y1"], x=zz1["x"], window=60, min_periods=12)
      4     return r1.beta

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in set_index(self, keys, drop, inplace, verify_integrity)
   2287             arrays.append(level)
   2288
-> 2289         index = MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=keys)
   2290
   2291         if verify_integrity and not index.is_unique:

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in from_arrays(cls, arrays, sortorder, names)
   1505         if len(arrays) == 1:
   1506             name = None if names is None else names[0]
-> 1507             return Index(arrays[0], name=name)
   1508
   1509         cats = [Categorical.from_array(arr) for arr in arrays]

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in __new__(cls, data, dtype, copy, name)
    102         if dtype is None:
    103             if (lib.is_datetime_array(subarr)
--> 104                 or lib.is_datetime64_array(subarr)
    105                 or lib.is_timestamp_array(subarr)):
    106                 from pandas.tseries.index import DatetimeIndex

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.is_datetime64_array (pandas/src/tseries.c:90291)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    427     def __getitem__(self, key):
    428         try:
--> 429             return self.index.get_value(self, key)
    430         except InvalidIndexError:
    431             pass

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
    639         """
    640         try:
--> 641             return self._engine.get_value(series, key)
    642         except KeyError, e1:
    643             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type == 'integer':

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/src/tseries.c:103842)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/src/tseries.c:103670)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/src/tseries.c:104379)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/src/tseries.c:15547)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/src/tseries.c:15501)()

KeyError: 0
```

But if I store off one of the group data frames, and then call `foo` on it, *this works just fine* ... ??

```
In [105]: for grp in grps:
    x = grp[1]
   .....:

In [106]: x.head()
Out[106]:
          x        y1        y2         z          dt  d
0  0.240858  0.235135  0.196027  0.940180  2000-01-01  1
1  0.115784  0.802576  0.870014  0.482418  2000-01-02  1
2  0.081640  0.939411  0.344041  0.846485  2000-01-03  1
5  0.608413  0.100349  0.306595  0.739987  2000-01-06  1
6  0.429635  0.678575  0.449520  0.362761  2000-01-07  1

In [107]: foo(x)
Out[107]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 360 entries, 2000-01-17 to 2001-12-29
Data columns:
x            360  non-null values
intercept    360  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2)
```

What's going on here? Does it have to do with cases when the logic to trigger conversion to bad date/time types is tripped? How can I work around it?

**Simplified Problem**

I can simplify the problem just to the `set_index` call within the `apply` function. But this is getting really weird. Here's an example with a simpler test DataFrame, just with `set_index`.

```
In [154]: tdf = pandas.DataFrame(
    {"dt":([datetime.date(2000,1,i+1) for i in range(12)] + 
           [datetime.date(2001,3,j+1) for j in range(13)]), 
     "d":np.random.randint(1,4,(25,)), 
     "x":np.random.rand(25)})

In [155]: tdf
Out[155]:
    d          dt         x
0   1  2000-01-01  0.430667
1   3  2000-01-02  0.159652
2   1  2000-01-03  0.719015
3   1  2000-01-04  0.175328
4   3  2000-01-05  0.233810
5   3  2000-01-06  0.581176
6   1  2000-01-07  0.912615
7   1  2000-01-08  0.534971
8   3  2000-01-09  0.373345
9   1  2000-01-10  0.182665
10  1  2000-01-11  0.286681
11  3  2000-01-12  0.054054
12  3  2001-03-01  0.861348
13  1  2001-03-02  0.093717
14  2  2001-03-03  0.729503
15  1  2001-03-04  0.888558
16  1  2001-03-05  0.263055
17  1  2001-03-06  0.558430
18  3  2001-03-07  0.064216
19  3  2001-03-08  0.018823
20  3  2001-03-09  0.207845
21  2  2001-03-10  0.735640
22  2  2001-03-11  0.908427
23  2  2001-03-12  0.819994
24  2  2001-03-13  0.798267
```

`set_index` works fine here, no date changing or anything.

```
In [156]: tdf.set_index("dt")
Out[156]:
            d         x
dt
2000-01-01  1  0.430667
2000-01-02  3  0.159652
2000-01-03  1  0.719015
2000-01-04  1  0.175328
2000-01-05  3  0.233810
2000-01-06  3  0.581176
2000-01-07  1  0.912615
2000-01-08  1  0.534971
2000-01-09  3  0.373345
2000-01-10  1  0.182665
2000-01-11  1  0.286681
2000-01-12  3  0.054054
2001-03-01  3  0.861348
2001-03-02  1  0.093717
2001-03-03  2  0.729503
2001-03-04  1  0.888558
2001-03-05  1  0.263055
2001-03-06  1  0.558430
2001-03-07  3  0.064216
2001-03-08  3  0.018823
2001-03-09  3  0.207845
2001-03-10  2  0.735640
2001-03-11  2  0.908427
2001-03-12  2  0.819994
2001-03-13  2  0.798267
```

`groupby` cannot successfully `set_index` though (note it errors before hitting any unpacking problems with incongruent sizes, it just cannot reset indices at all).

```
In [157]: tdf.groupby("d").apply(lambda x: x.set_index("dt"))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-157-cf2d3964f4d3> in <module>()
----> 1 tdf.groupby("d").apply(lambda x: x.set_index("dt"))

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    267         applied : type depending on grouped object and function
    268         """
--> 269         return self._python_apply_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
    270
    271     def aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs):

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _python_apply_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    402             group_axes = _get_axes(group)
    403
--> 404             res = func(group, *args, **kwargs)
    405
    406             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):

<ipython-input-157-cf2d3964f4d3> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 tdf.groupby("d").apply(lambda x: x.set_index("dt"))

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in set_index(self, keys, drop, inplace, verify_integrity)
   2287             arrays.append(level)
   2288
-> 2289         index = MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=keys)
   2290
   2291         if verify_integrity and not index.is_unique:

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in from_arrays(cls, arrays, sortorder, names)
   1505         if len(arrays) == 1:
   1506             name = None if names is None else names[0]
-> 1507             return Index(arrays[0], name=name)
   1508
   1509         cats = [Categorical.from_array(arr) for arr in arrays]

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in __new__(cls, data, dtype, copy, name)
    102         if dtype is None:
    103             if (lib.is_datetime_array(subarr)
--> 104                 or lib.is_datetime64_array(subarr)
    105                 or lib.is_timestamp_array(subarr)):
    106                 from pandas.tseries.index import DatetimeIndex

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.is_datetime64_array (pandas/src/tseries.c:90291)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    427     def __getitem__(self, key):
    428         try:
--> 429             return self.index.get_value(self, key)
    430         except InvalidIndexError:
    431             pass

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
    639         """
    640         try:
--> 641             return self._engine.get_value(series, key)
    642         except KeyError, e1:
    643             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type == 'integer':

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/src/tseries.c:103842)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/src/tseries.c:103670)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/src/tseries.c:104379)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/src/tseries.c:15547)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/src/tseries.c:15501)()

KeyError: 0
```

**Very weird part**

Here I save off the group objects, and try to manually call `set_index` on them. This doesn't work. Even if I save out the specific DataFrame element from the group, it does not work.

```
In [159]: grps = tdf.groupby("d")

In [160]: grps
Out[160]: <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy at 0x7600bd0>

In [161]: grps_list = [(x,y) for x,y in grps]

In [162]: grps_list[2][1].set_index("dt")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-162-77f985a6e063> in <module>()
----> 1 grps_list[2][1].set_index("dt")

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in set_index(self, keys, drop, inplace, verify_integrity)
   2287             arrays.append(level)
   2288
-> 2289         index = MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=keys)
   2290
   2291         if verify_integrity and not index.is_unique:

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in from_arrays(cls, arrays, sortorder, names)
   1505         if len(arrays) == 1:
   1506             name = None if names is None else names[0]
-> 1507             return Index(arrays[0], name=name)
   1508
   1509         cats = [Categorical.from_array(arr) for arr in arrays]

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in __new__(cls, data, dtype, copy, name)
    102         if dtype is None:
    103             if (lib.is_datetime_array(subarr)
--> 104                 or lib.is_datetime64_array(subarr)
    105                 or lib.is_timestamp_array(subarr)):
    106                 from pandas.tseries.index import DatetimeIndex

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.is_datetime64_array (pandas/src/tseries.c:90291)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    427     def __getitem__(self, key):
    428         try:
--> 429             return self.index.get_value(self, key)
    430         except InvalidIndexError:
    431             pass

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
    639         """
    640         try:
--> 641             return self._engine.get_value(series, key)
    642         except KeyError, e1:
    643             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type == 'integer':

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/src/tseries.c:103842)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/src/tseries.c:103670)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/src/tseries.c:104379)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/src/tseries.c:15547)()

/opt/epd/7.3-2_pandas0.8.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/src/tseries.c:15501)()

KeyError: 0
```

*But if I construct a manual direct copy of the group's DataFrame, then `set_index` **does** work on the manual reconstruction??*

```
In [163]: grps_list[2][1]
Out[163]:
    d          dt         x
1   3  2000-01-02  0.159652
4   3  2000-01-05  0.233810
5   3  2000-01-06  0.581176
8   3  2000-01-09  0.373345
11  3  2000-01-12  0.054054
12  3  2001-03-01  0.861348
18  3  2001-03-07  0.064216
19  3  2001-03-08  0.018823
20  3  2001-03-09  0.207845

In [165]: recreation = pandas.DataFrame(
    {"d":[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3], 
     "dt":[datetime.date(2000,1,2), datetime.date(2000,1,5), datetime.date(2000,1,6),
           datetime.date(2000,1,9), datetime.date(2000,1,12), datetime.date(2001,3,1),
           datetime.date(2001,3,7), datetime.date(2001,3,8), datetime.date(2001,3,9)], 
     "x":[0.159, 0.233, 0.581, 0.3733, 0.054, 0.861, 0.064, 0.0188, 0.2078]})

In [166]: recreation
Out[166]:
   d          dt       x
0  3  2000-01-02  0.1590
1  3  2000-01-05  0.2330
2  3  2000-01-06  0.5810
3  3  2000-01-09  0.3733
4  3  2000-01-12  0.0540
5  3  2001-03-01  0.8610
6  3  2001-03-07  0.0640
7  3  2001-03-08  0.0188
8  3  2001-03-09  0.2078

In [167]: recreation.set_index("dt")
Out[167]:
            d       x
dt
2000-01-02  3  0.1590
2000-01-05  3  0.2330
2000-01-06  3  0.5810
2000-01-09  3  0.3733
2000-01-12  3  0.0540
2001-03-01  3  0.8610
2001-03-07  3  0.0640
2001-03-08  3  0.0188
2001-03-09  3  0.2078
```

As the pirates might say in the first few episodes of Archer Season 3: What hell damn guy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is based on something that happens in `groupby` which changes indices of the groups into a MultiIndex.

By adding a call to reset the index inside of the function to be applied with `apply`, it gets rid of the problem:

```
def foo(zz):
    zz1 = zz.sort("dt", ascending=True).reset_index().set_index("dt", inplace=True)
    r1 = pandas.ols(y=zz1["y1"], x=zz1["x"], window=60, min_periods=12)
    return r1.beta
```

and this at least provides a workaround.